# Rails bi-directional accepts_nested_attributes_for causes double save and loss of dirty attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have 2 models as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks

  before_save :test
  after_save :test2

  def test
    puts "before save #{changes}"
  end

  def test2
    puts "after save #{saved_changes}"
  end
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

After running this:

```
u = User.new(name: 'def')
u.tasks_attributes = [{ name: 'abc' }]
u.save!
```

The result is:

```
before save {"name"=>[nil, "def"]}
D, [2019-03-13T08:16:27.972711 #53578] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2019-03-13T08:16:27.973374 #53578] DEBUG -- :   User Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name") VALUES (?)  [["name", "def"]]
before save {}
after save {}
D, [2019-03-13T08:16:27.974821 #53578] DEBUG -- :   Task Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("user_id", "name") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["name", "abc"]]
after save {}
```

As you can see, the autosave is causing the User to get re-saved from the task, even though it is the user that is creating the task in the first place, leading to attribute changes getting lost.

The same code where we remove accepts_nested_attributes_for from the task model, we get the expected result:

```
before save {"name"=>[nil, "def"]}
D, [2019-03-13T08:50:20.629287 #54423] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2019-03-13T08:50:20.629689 #54423] DEBUG -- :   User Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name") VALUES (?)  [["name", "def"]]
D, [2019-03-13T08:50:20.630990 #54423] DEBUG -- :   Task Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("user_id", "name") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["name", "abc"]]
after save {"id"=>[nil, 1], "name"=>[nil, "def"]}
D, [2019-03-13T08:50:20.631626 #54423] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  commit transaction
```

I have tracked this down to the fact that autosave is always true when accepts_nested_attributes_for is present and this line here:

```
saved = record.save(validate: !autosave) if record.new_record? || (autosave && record.changed_for_autosave?)
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L479

Any way around this?

Comment: what version of rails? do you need the `inverse of` for that version of rails?

Comment: Using Rails 5.2.2. The same behaviour is observed with or without inverse_of

Comment: how are the attribute changes getting lost?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon as you can see I am logging the before_save and after_save change attributes. Since save ends up being called twice, we go to before_save twice, then after_save where the saved_changes are NOT present as they should be.

Comment: i do not understand your examples. are you able to clarify in any way?

Comment: Let's say I want to create a user with some tasks. And after saving, if the user is a new user, I want to send them an email.

So I can do 

```
User.create(name: "John", tasks_attributes: [{ name: "Do some work" }])
```

Now in after save I want to check if the user id was changed, i.e. it is a new record.

But since autosave is saving it twice, the saved_changes attribute is always blank even though I did just create the record.